Basecamp 3 authorize with Apps Script
I would really appreciate some help here. I have a script with these functions:
function getOAuthService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('Basecamp')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/new')
    .setTokenUrl('https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/token')
    .setClientId('client_id')
    .setClientSecret('secret')
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setScope('read')
    .setParam('type', 'web_server')
    .setRedirectUri('https://script.google.com/macros/d/SCRIPT_ID/usercallback');
}

function authorize() {
  var basecampService = getOAuthService();
  if (!basecampService.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = basecampService.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: ' + authorizationUrl);
  } else {
    Logger.log('You are already authorized.');
  }
}

The client_id, secret and script_id are actual ids and are legit. When I run the authorize() function I get the URL and open it and it takes me to the page where I can allow access and authorize. However, when I do, I just get this message:
Error: Error retrieving token: Unsupported type. Expected "web_server" or "refresh". (line 605, file "Service")
I have no idea why and can't find a fix. Any ideas? Thanks!
I can't really try a lot myself since I'm not a developer, just trying to do this to automate some stuff

Had some strange fortune and found out that there is a Basecamp sample code on the OAuth2 github page that does exactly what I need and it works, awesome

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
